# Django model polymorphic related field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to remove duplicate code within my Django models. As you can see in the code below, the only difference between `send_salary_notification` and `send_pension_notifications` is that one uses the related field `jurisdiction` and the other uses `agency`. How can I refactor the code so that jurisdiction/agency is set once, based off `record_type`?

I tried creating a class variable as `record_type`, and in that first function set the variable with `cls.record_type = record_type`, then this:

```
agencies_changed.append(subscription.record_type)
```

But that gives an error that record_type is not a valid instance.

Here is my code:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=get_key_expiration)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def send_notifications(cls, record_type, slugs):
        """
        Sends notifications for all subscribers.
        """
        subscribers = cls.objects.all()
        for subscriber in subscribers:
            if record_type == 'salary':
                subscriber.send_salary_notifications(slugs, record_type)
            elif record_type == 'pension':
                subscriber.send_pension_notifications(slugs, record_type)

    def send_salary_notifications(self, slugs, record_type):
        matching_subscriptions = self.get_matching_salary_subscriptions(slugs)
        agencies_changed = []

        if not matching_subscriptions:
            return None

        for subscription in matching_subscriptions:
            agencies_changed.append(subscription.jurisdiction)
            self.update_salary_last_year_sent(subscription)

        message = self.build_notification_message(agencies_changed, record_type)
        self.send_notification_email(message)

    def send_pension_notifications(self, slugs, record_type):
        matching_subscriptions = self.get_matching_pension_subscriptions(slugs)
        agencies_changed = []

        if not matching_subscriptions:
            return None

        for subscription in matching_subscriptions:
            agencies_changed.append(subscription.agency)
            self.update_pension_last_year_sent(subscription)

        message = self.build_notification_message(agencies_changed, record_type)
        self.send_notification_email(message)


class SalarySubscription(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey('subscriptions.Subscriber', related_name='salary_subscriptions')
    jurisdiction = models.ForeignKey('jurisdiction.Jurisdiction')
    last_year_sent = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)


class PensionSubscription(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey('subscriptions.Subscriber', related_name='pension_subscriptions')
    agency = models.ForeignKey('pensions.Agency')
    last_year_sent = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to change `get_matching_pension_subscriptions`, `get_matching_salary_subscriptions`, `update_salary_last_year_sent` and `update_pension_last_year_sent` methods,you can refactor your code to following. You can define a single notification method and get related attributes dynamically using `getattr` builtin depending on `record_type`. There may be other refactoring solutions fitting more nicely in your code base but seeing piece of code you posted this solution is very reasonable.

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def send_notifications(cls, record_type, slugs):
        """
        Sends notifications for all subscribers.
        """
        subscribers = cls.objects.all()
        for subscriber in subscribers:
            subscriber._send_notification(record_type, slugs)

    def _send_notification(self, record_type, slugs):
        matching_subscriptions = getattr(self, 'get_matching_{}_subscriptions'.format(record_type))(slugs)
        if not matching_subscriptions:
            return None

        agencies_changed = []
        agency_attribute = {
            'salary': 'jurisdiction',
            'pension': 'agency'
        }[record_type]

        for subscription in matching_subscriptions:
            agencies_changed.append(getattr(subscription, agency_attribute))
            getattr(self, 'update_{}_last_year_sent'.format(record_type))(subscription)

        message = self.build_notification_message(agencies_changed, record_type)
        self.send_notification_email(message)
```